# Printing only some properties of an object using for-in loop and if-else

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, for-in-loop

I am wondering how to get only some of the elements of an object using **only** for-in and if-else.

For example, if we have the following object:

```
var person,
property;

person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    profession: "Lawyer",
    age: 31,
    eyeColor: "blue",
    hairColor: "blonde"
}
```

How do I print out only the second and fourth property of this object with for-in and if-else?

Comment: do you want the second and fourth property regardless what property it will be? or do you want lastName and age?

Comment: I want the second and fourth property regardless what that property will be. And I know about the "person.age" way for example, but I need to do it with for-in loop and if-else

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops, you can simply access the value of the object like this

```
person.lastName
person.age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var person,
    property,
    count,
    wantedProperties;

person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    profession: "Lawyer",
    age: 31,
    eyeColor: "blue",
    hairColor: "blonde"
};

count = 1;
wantedProperties = [2,4];

for (prop in person) {
    if (inArray(count, wantedProperties)) {
        console.log(prop);
    }
    count++;
}

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The helper function inArray is necessary, because wantedProperties.indexOf(count) doesn't work properly since wantedProperties is an array of ints.

Also, it's ugly, that it's not zero-based. You might want to refactor the code, but I wanted to be readable the best I could.

If you want to log the value of the property, change `console.log(prop);` to `console.log(person[prop]);`